# How can I response function blocked by website?

Tags: html, python-requests

I am trying to grab the data table in url = 'https://quotes.wsj.com/index/HK/XHKG/HSI/historical-prices/download?num_rows=150&range_days=150&endDate=02/29/2020'. I clicked on the link and a csv file will be download. Therefore, the link is correct. However, from the response.content, there is message saying "The request could not be satisfied.Request blocked." Can server distinguish manual click and python Request and block it? Any way to work around it?

My codes:

```
import requests

url = 'https://quotes.wsj.com/index/HK/XHKG/HSI/historical-prices/download?num_rows=150&range_days=150&endDate=02/29/2020'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
open('wsj.csv', 'wb').write(response.content)
```

Comment: I don't believe that you can. It is blocked before the connection can get what you are asking for. Either by the the site or by your code.

Comment: Thanks.  The link is not blocked from manual click. Anyway to work around it?